# CakePHP adding new database session in every request

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am using Cakephp4 database sessions. I've noticed that every request adds a new row in the `sessions` table. I don't want sessions to timeout, and I don't want users to re-login. Following is the `bootstrap.php` config and my `app.php` config.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'timeout' => 518400, //1 year,
    //'autoRegenerate' => true,    
    
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'handler' => [
        'engine' => 'ComboSession',
        'model' => 'Sessions'
    ],
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_samesite' => 'none',
        'session.cookie_secure' => 'true'        
    )
));
```

**ComboSession.php**

```
class ComboSession extends DatabaseSession
{
    protected $cacheKey;

    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
    }

    // Read data from the session.
    public function read($id): string
    {

        Log::debug($id . '=>reading session');

        return parent::read($id);
    }

    // Write data into the session.
    public function write($id, $data): bool
    {

        Log::debug($id . '=>writing session=>' . print_r(debug_backtrace(2), true));
        parent::destroy($id);
        return parent::write($id, $data);
    }

    // Destroy a session.
    public function destroy($id): bool
    {

        Log::debug($id . '=>destroying a session');
        return parent::destroy($id);
    }

    // Removes expired sessions.
    public function gc($expires = null): bool
    {
        Log::debug($expires . '=>Calling Gc for a session');
        return parent::gc($expires);
    }
}
```

Following is trace as well

```
2024-01-03 22:11:39 Debug: hkmra7g50t391n9o9hk7u9caur=>writing session=>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [function] => write
            [class] => App\Http\Session\ComboSession
            [type] => ->
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Session.php
            [line] => 387
            [function] => session_write_close
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Server.php
            [line] => 93
            [function] => close
            [class] => Cake\Http\Session
            [type] => ->
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => webroot\index.php
            [line] => 40
            [function] => run
            [class] => Cake\Http\Server
            [type] => ->
        )

)
```

I am not setting anything in my `AppController.php` that would add a new session. If anything, it should update the current session/row rather than adding a new one.

Comment: The issue you're experiencing might be due to the write method in your ComboSession class. In this method, you're destroying the session before writing to it, which could cause a new session to be created on every request.

Comment: Actually I added that code as a trial, Its been going on before that and still happens even if I remove it

Answer (score 0):

Then, I suppose the issue is not with the `write` method in your `ComboSession` class. One possible cause could be the `session.cookie_secure` setting in your `Session` configuration. This setting is set to `true,` meaning the session cookie will only be sent over secure HTTPS connections. If your application runs on HTTP during development, the session cookie might not be sent with each request, causing a new session to be created.

You can try setting `session.cookie_secure` to `false` in your local development environment to see if that resolves the issue. You can do this in your `.env` file:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=false
```

Then, in your `Session` configuration, use this environment variable:

```php
'ini' => array(
    'session.cookie_samesite' => 'none',
    'session.cookie_secure' => env('SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE', 'true')        
)
```

This way, the `session.cookie_secure` setting will be `false` in your local development environment (assuming you're not using HTTPS). However, it will default to `true` in other environments unless explicitly set in the `.env` file.

If this doesn't solve the issue, you might need to debug your application further to find the cause. Check if any other part of your code could be causing a new session to be created on each request.

Comment: I am using HTTPS, im debugging code to check if I am renewing session at any point. I am writing data to session if the data changes but should that not update the session? Why is it adding a new row

Comment: I'm not sure. To debug this issue, you can log the session ID and any changes to the session data. This might help you identify when and why a new session is being created.